# How to combine boto with fabric

Tags: python, boto, fabric

I need to mention. I use Windows.

Now I know how to use boto. But I faced the problem that I can't run "sudo" based on boto.

```
status, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.run('sudo python killerparser.py')
```

The error is that **sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo**

And then I try to run it.

```
status, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.run('ssh -t localhost sudo python killerparser.py')
```

But now the error becomes **'Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.\r\nHost key verification failed.'**

I don't want to change user-data which is unsafe. So It comes up to the idea to use fabric. But how to define the host and key path? I think fabric is not object based which is really frustrating.
My all code:

```
import boto.ec2
from boto.manage.cmdshell import sshclient_from_instance
from  fabric.api import env, run, cd, settings, sudo,hosts;

env.host = 'ec2-user@#.#.#.#'
env.user = "ec2-user"
env.key_filename = "D:\key.pem"
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1',aws_access_key_id="***",aws_secret_access_key="*")
instance = conn.get_all_instances(['***'])[0].instances[0]
ssh_client = sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                     ssh_key_file='**',
                                     user_name='ec2-user')
sudo("cd ~");
sudo("python killerparser.py");
```

Now there is no error. But it can't execute the shell

The killerparser.py

```
import subprocess, signal,os;

for line in os.popen("ps ax | grep -i newLive.py"):
        if "grep" in line: continue;
        fields = line.split()
        pid = fields[0]
        os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
proc = subprocess.Popen('sudo python newLive.py 2>newLive.err', shell=True,
             stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
```

Comment: why not use sudo function from fabric?

Comment: @Rozuur I did. But the error is the connection.

Comment: set your hosts, env.host="host" or invoke `fab -H <host>' in your terminal

Comment: env.host = 'ec2-#-#-#-#.compute-1.amazonaws.com' I did, but the problem is same.

Comment: Question.. if you have the hostname/ip of the box why are you mixing and matching boto with fabric, and just use fabric to make the connection. Query ec2 the same way you're doing now, just use fabric to make the connection and not boto. I dont know, it will at least simplify the code.

Comment: boto would allow you to use sudo. I mean it doesn't work @JavierBuzzi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with two things you're doing. One: `sudo python...` No. Make that run as www-data or equivalent. Also, use `supervisord` and not what you're currently doing.

Shouldn't matter if you're on windows or not.. You're telling me this doesn't work for you?

fabfile.py:

```
import boto.ec2
from fabric.api import env, run, sudo, task

env.key_filename = "/PATH/TO/SSH/FILE.pem"
env.user = "ubuntu"

@task
def amazon(**kwargs):
    conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(
        'us-east-1',
        aws_access_key_id="*********",
        aws_secret_access_key="**************"
    )

    hosts = []
    for reservation in conn.get_all_instances():
        for instance in reservation.instances:
            # if filters were applied
            if kwargs:
                skip_instance = False
                for key, value in kwargs.items():
                    instance_value = getattr(instance, key)

                    # makes sure that `group` is handeled
                    if isinstance(instance_value, list):
                        new_value = []
                        for item in instance_value:
                            if isinstance(item, boto.ec2.group.Group):
                                new_value.append(item.name)
                            else:
                                new_value.append(item)
                        instance_value = new_value

                        if value not in instance_value:
                            skip_instance = True
                            break
                    else:
                        # every other single value gets handeled here
                        if instance_value != value:
                            skip_instance = True
                            break

                if skip_instance:
                    continue

            if instance.dns_name:
                hosts.append(instance.dns_name)
            elif instance.ip_address:
                hosts.append(instance.ip_address)

    env.hosts = hosts


@task
def whoami():
    run('whoami')
    sudo('whoami')
```

I added filters for you, just in case, you can run it as:

`fab amazon whoami` -- it will go through every single server in amazon and connect and run `whoami` commands.

`fab amazon:ip_address=<IP OF AN INSTANCE YOU KNOW OF> whoami` -- will only use the box whos ip matched on the filter. (It should work for every field in the `instance` in boto)

that one is just a gimmick, `groups` is the one "I" would use:

`fab amazon:groups=<GROUP NAME FROM AMAZON> whoami` -- will run `whoami` on all servers that matched said group name.

proof:

```
$ fab amazon:dns_name=******* whoami
[*******] Executing task 'whoami'
[*******] run: whoami
[*******] out: ubuntu
[*******] out: 

[*******] sudo: whoami
[*******] out: root
[*******] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from *******... done.
```

and

```
$ fab amazon:groups=webservers whoami
[***1***] Executing task 'whoami'
[***1***] run: whoami
[***1***] out: ubuntu
[***1***] out: 

[***1***] sudo: whoami
[***1***] out: root
[***1***] out: 

... truncated...

[***4***] Executing task 'whoami'
[***4***] run: whoami
[***4***] out: ubuntu
[***4***] out: 

[***4***] sudo: whoami
[***4***] out: root
[***4***] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from ***1***... done.
Disconnecting from ***2***... done.
Disconnecting from ***3***... done.
Disconnecting from ***4***... done.
Disconnecting from ***5***... done.
Disconnecting from ***6***... done.
Disconnecting from ***7***... done.
```