# Retrieve IP from json with fabric

Tags: python, json, linux, fabric

Hi I have a json something like below i want to retrieve **ip_address** & store it in any variable in fabric.And if my **ip_address** (v4) field is array how can i use different ip set automatically on my [env.host] variable.

```
 {
 "droplet":{
 "id":16549167,
 "name":"test",
 "memory":512,
 "vcpus":1,
 "disk":20,
 "locked":false,
 "status":"active",
 "kernel":null,
 "created_at":"2016-06-03T07:01:59Z",
 "features":[
 "ipv6",
 "virtio"
            ],
 "next_backup_window":null,
 "snapshot_ids":[
     ],
 "image":{
 "id":17154032,
 "name":"14.04.4 x64",
 "distribution":"Ubuntu",
 "slug":"ubuntu-14-04-x64",
 "public":true,
 "regions":[
 "nyc1",
 "tor1",
 "sfo2",
 "blr1"
           ],
 "created_at":"2016-05-04T22:25:47Z",
 "min_disk_size":20,
 "type":"snapshot",
   "size_gigabytes":19.68 
           },
 "size":{
 "slug":"512mb",
 "memory":512,

"available":true
         },
 "networks":{
       "v4":[
            {
          "ip_address":"104.236.223.78",
          "netmask":"255.255.192.0",
          "gateway":"104.236.192.1",
          "type":"public"
            }
           ],
       "v6":[
       {
       "ip_address":"260:A880:08:001",
       "netmask":64,
      "gateway":"2604:800:0010:0000:0000:0000:0001",
        "type":"public"
  }
  ]
   }
```

Comment: Ok, you want you call boto and extract all the ips and remote into them? Yes?

Comment: I wrote something similar a while back that i think it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094758/how-to-combine-boto-with-fabric/34160608#34160608 it integrates amazon/aws already using boto. And lets you call whatever box you want by `id` `group` .. anything really.. If you need something more specific let me know, but i think this will help you.

Comment: Oh i see. this is for digitalocean not aws/amazon .. you need to use `doto` instead of `boto` -- same concept though.

Comment: Can you please explain your question better?